# Resteasy is not working with wildfly 11 but fine with Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, wildfly, resteasy

I have created a maven project with 3 sub modules, first module with common api, second module for rest ws with resteasy and the third module for hibernate persistence. These three modules are dependent each other. When i generate war file out of it and deployed in wildfly getting below error.

```
18:30:59,620 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Library_books
18:30:59,784 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Library-management-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war#Library_books'
18:30:59,818 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Library_books
    ...]
18:30:59,827 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Library_books
18:30:59,869 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment library-management-system.war
18:30:59,860 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment Library-management-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
18:30:59,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'library-management-system.war#Library_books'
18:30:59,895 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Library_books
    ...]
18:30:59,939 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
18:30:59,969 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.10.Final}
18:30:59,971 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
18:30:59,973 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
18:31:00,060 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
18:31:00,104 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."library-management-system.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."library-management-system.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "library-management-system.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.library-management-system.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:421)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.library-management-system.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:419)
    ... 8 more

18:31:00,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
18:31:00,422 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Library</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
         org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
      </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Library-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.subhash.apps.library.management.app.LibraryApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Library-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

resteasy dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Below dependency is for JAXB integration -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
<version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You have jar pollution. Please list all the 3rd party jars in your application (there's no need to show your own jars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue here. I have deployed same application which build using jersy. In wildfly that war file was present which is the root cause of this error.
I have removed the war file from 
standalone\deployments
and from tmp folder as well, which fixed the issue.

Thanks!